# Grails: Disable mandatory field validation in GSP

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I created a domain class as below

```
class Sender {

String senderFname;
String senderLname;
String senderPhone;
String senderState;

List receivers

static hasMany = [receivers: Receiver]

static constraints = {

    senderFname blank: false, nullable: false
    senderLname blank: false, nullable: false
    senderPhone blank: false, nullable: false
    senderState blank: false, nulllable: false

}   
}
```

I generated the default views and everything works well. Now I am developing a simple search form for this domain class where non of fields are mandatory. I created a search.gsp and reused code from create template(_form.gsp) so that I can do request binding in search action. Now I cann't to disable front end JS validation on this form.

I looked for the code that does front end validation, but I couldn't find where its located.

I am on grails 2.0.1

Answer (score 2):

It's actually HTML5 validation - just remove **required** attribute from textField tags.